# strtolower does not work in codeigniter 3 framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have written code in CodeIgniter 3 framework, but it inserts into database empty value. However, if I delete strtolower() function, it works properly and inserts data into the database. Where can be the problem?

```
        $slugtitle = strtolower($this->input->post('name'));
        $slug = url_title($slugtitle);

        $data = array(
            'courses_description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'purpose' => $this->input->post('purpose'),
            'courses_slug' => $slug
        );
```

When I write `var_dump($this->input->post('name'))` it shows

> string(20) "Cavidin Əmisi Azər"

I want this to insert like "cavidin-əmisi-azər". When I remove strtolower() it inserts "Cavidin-Əmisi-Azər".

Comment: If the posted name is empty than strtolower can't do anything with it, and it stays empty.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Give us a sample of a string that you're trying. `var_dump($this->input->post('name'))`

Comment: @deceze it gives: string(20) "Cavidin Əmisi Azər"

Comment: Put that in your question; this will be something specific to locales/encodings…

Comment: I want this to insert like: "cavidin-əmisi-azər". When I remove strtolower() it inserts "Cavidin-Əmisi-Azər"

Comment: What language is this? What character set? I thought mb_strtolower could handle your needs, but it's not working, and I'm curious.

Comment: @BrianGottier it is PHP CodeIgniter 3 framework. UTF-8 charset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`mb_strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) function

```
$slugtitle = mb_strtolower($this->input->post('name'), 'UTF-8');
```

You can see the example [here](https://repl.it/K2Uw/0)

Comment: can you explain please, why this code works but strtolower not?

Comment: Sorry you have right, because it's Multibytes String and it's used for multi language support but it's slower.. You can see here [the fully explanation](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php)